# Why does Blazor CascadingParameter from my layout page return null to the children on full reload of the page?

Tags: .net, blazor

I have a Blazor .net 8 web app I am working on and have a couple cascading parameters in the main layout page of the app which passes a session id through local storage and also a "Booking" model which grabs any current bookings based on that session id from the database. On first load and any loading done through the site everything works great and all the values populate properly. When I reload the page either pressing "enter" on the address bar or hitting "f5" i get a null error. I checked the session id from the main layout and it shows up as well as the "Booking" model. But inside the child component which i am trying to use the cascading parameter both values are null. Now I am using an async method on the main layout page because of the GetAsync method of the localstorage property, so what i am thinking is that the rest of the components loaded faster than the GetAsync method has assigned the variables to the main layout component. My main issue is I don't know what else i can do to make this work.

Here is my Calendar page where I try to display the session id and get that error:

```
@if (booking is not null)
{
    <div class="calendar">
        <CalendarToggle booking="booking" OnStatusChange="StatusChanged" />
        <CalendarMonthSelector calendarMonth="calendarMonth" changeMonth="ChangeMonth" />
        <CalendarDaysOfWeek />
        <CalendarDays daysInMonth="daysInMonth" status="status" booking="booking" calendarMonth="calendarMonth" offsetDays="offsetDays" calendarBookings="calendarBookings" />
    </div>

    <br />
    **<div>Session ID: @booking.SessionId</div>**
    <div>Current Date: @DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now)</div>
    <div>Calendar Month: @calendarMonth.ToString("MMMM yyyy")</div>
    <div>Days In Month: @daysInMonth</div>
    <div>Offset Days: @offsetDays</div>
    <br />
}
else
{
    <p>Loading...</p>
}


@code {
    **[CascadingParameter(Name = "SessionId")]
    private ProtectedBrowserStorageResult<string> sessionId { get; set; }

    [CascadingParameter(Name = "CurrentBooking")]
    private Booking? currentBooking { get; set; }**

    private DateOnly calendarMonth { get; set; }
    private int daysInMonth { get; set; }
    private int offsetDays { get; set; }
    private bool status { get; set; }
    private List<CalendarVM>? calendarBookings { get; set; }
    public BookingDatesVM? booking { get; set; } = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        calendarMonth = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
        status = true;
        PopulateVariables();
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        booking.SessionId = Guid.Parse(sessionId.Value);
    }

    private void PopulateVariables()
    {
        daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(calendarMonth.Year, calendarMonth.Month);
        offsetDays = DateUtility.GetOffset(calendarMonth);
        PopulateCalendar();
    }

.....rest of code irrelevant.
```

Here is my MainLayout page:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject TimerService timerService
@inject ProtectedLocalStorage localStorage
@inject IBookingRepository bookingRepository
@implements IDisposable

<div class="wrapper">
    <header>
        <NavMenu />
        @if (timerService.showTimer)
        {
            <CountdownTimer />
        }
        **@result.Value**
    </header>

    **<CascadingValue Value="@result" Name="SessionId">
        <CascadingValue Value="@currentBooking" Name="CurrentBooking">
            <main>
                @Body
            </main>
        </CascadingValue>
    </CascadingValue>**

    <footer class="darkBG">
        <Footer />
    </footer>
</div>

@code {
    private Booking? currentBooking { get; set; }
    public ProtectedBrowserStorageResult<string> result { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        bookingRepository.DeleteStaleBookings();
        await GetLocalStorage();
        if (currentBooking!.CheckInDate != DateOnly.MinValue)
        {
            timerService.ShowTimer();
        }
    }

    public async Task GetLocalStorage()
    {
        result = await localStorage.GetAsync<string>(SettingsUtility.sessionId);

        if (!result.Success)
        {
            await localStorage.SetAsync(SettingsUtility.sessionId, Guid.NewGuid());
            result = await localStorage.GetAsync<string>(SettingsUtility.sessionId);
        }

        currentBooking = bookingRepository.GetBySessionId(Guid.Parse(result.Value!));

        if (currentBooking is null)
        {
            currentBooking = new Booking();
            currentBooking.SessionId = Guid.Parse(result.Value!);
        }
    }

    private void OnStateChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e) => StateHasChanged();
    public void Dispose() => timerService.StateChanged -= OnStateChanged;
}
```

[image: Here is the image before the error and both the header and the main page will display the session id properly.]

[image: Here is the error I get after refreshing the browser on the same page]

I have tried using the OnParametersSet override which is what i show here.
I have also used the OnAfterRender override to try and assign the properties after the page has been rendered and still can't get the values to show up.

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: It sounds really strange that you could read and set values with ProtectedLocalStorage inside OnInitializedAsync() method of mainlayout component,for js interop hasn't be issued during prerendering

Comment: as stated in the document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-8.0&pivots=server#save-and-load-data-within-a-component     "The examples in this section only work if the server doesn't have prerendering enabled. With prerendering enabled, an error is generated explaining that JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued because the component is being prerendered."

Comment: You almost certainly have interactivity set at *Per Page/Component* and Routes and Layout are statically rendered.  The answer below provides some detail.  If that's what you want you will need to register the cascading value in services.  See this answer on how to do it and change the value - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77448224/how-to-use-cascadingvaluesource

Comment: @RuikaiFeng does this issue only apply to the fact that i am using ProtectedBrowserStorageResult to store the value and then assigning it that way? I tried storing the variable in a string from the MainLayout component and then using that as a cascading value and its working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the [doucment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-8.0#cascading-valuesparameters-and-render-mode-boundaries) related:

> Cascading parameters don't pass data across render mode boundaries:
>
> Interactive sessions run in a different context than the pages that
> use static server-side rendering (static SSR). There's no requirement
> that the server producing the page is even the same machine that hosts
> some later Interactive Server session, including for WebAssembly
> components where the server is a different machine to the client. The
> benefit of static server-side rendering (static SSR) is to gain the
> full performance of pure stateless HTML rendering.
>
> State crossing the boundary between static and interactive rendering
> must be serializable. Components are arbitrary objects that reference
> a vast chain of other objects, including the renderer, the DI
> container, and every DI service instance. You must explicitly cause
> state to be serialized from static SSR to make it available in
> subsequent interactively-rendered components. Two approaches are
> adopted:
>
> Via the Blazor framework, parameters passed across a static SSR to
> interactive rendering boundary are serialized automatically if they're
> JSON-serializable, or an error is thrown. State stored in
> PersistentComponentState is serialized and recovered automatically if
> it's JSON-serializable, or an error is thrown.

Comment: What would be the point of cascading values if you can't pass it down with a chance that the value won't make it? I'm sorry for the noob question but I'm trying to understand it all. I don't have prerendering enabled. It's disabled application wide.

Comment: Hi,@alex cardoso,do you mean you disabled prerendering via <Routes @rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode(false)"/> in app.razor?