# Passing data from Main.razor to layout in Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I want to pass some data (simple types and RenderFragment) to my layout, which I want to serve a component from a separate Razor library. I found some posts about doing it from pages, but I only want to write it one place. I'm not sure how to achieve this. Current code:

Layout:

```
public sealed partial class MainLayout
{
   [CascadingParameter] public string TeamName { get; set; }
   [CascadingParameter] public string TeamIcon { get; set; }
   private string Version => $"Version: {GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version!.ToString()}";
   [CascadingParameter] public RenderFragment NavMenuContent { get; set; }

   private bool _drawerOpen;
   
   private Task ToggleDrawer()
   {
       _drawerOpen = !_drawerOpen;
       return Task.CompletedTask;
   }
}
```

Main.razor

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Main).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)"/>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <MudAlert Variant="Variant.Filled" Severity="Severity.Warning">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</MudAlert>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

NavMenu:

```
<MudNavMenu>
    @ChildContent
    <NavGroup Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Info" Title="Info" Expanded="false">
        <NavLink Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.AddIcCall" Href="/support" Text="Support"/>
    </NavGroup>
    <NavLink Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.History" Href="/execution-history" Text="Executions history"/>
    <NavLink Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Settings" Href="/application-settings" Text="Application settings"/>
</MudNavMenu>
```

Comment: You can add root cascading values -  see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-8.0#root-level-cascading-values and modify them like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77448224/how-to-use-cascadingvaluesource.  However, you shouldn't be passing  around `RenderFragments`.  Why not different NavMenu components? You then pass the Type and use `DynamicComponent` to render it.

Comment: I used the root cascading values and it worked, thanks :). Could please elaborate on why I should not pass around the RenderFragment? In my case, I've got the layout in which I've got the NavMenu. In that NavMenu, I have some links I always need at the bottom, the rest will be depend on the application. I've added a screenshot for you reference.

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer and a bit of info on RenderFragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add root cascading values - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-8.0#root-level-cascading-values and modify them like this: [How to use CascadingValueSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77448224/how-to-use-cascadingvaluesource).

If your RenderFragment is in a standalone class that you instantiate, or is a static pure function then OK.  If it's part of another component then there's no guarantee about it's state.  Components are instantiated and disposed by the Renderer, not you.